# debug error in visual studio

Tags: c++

can somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong here, I receive an error unexpected end of file and also missing function header, thanks in advance

```
static char debug[256];

#define DBGPRINT(...)           {sprintf_s(debug, 256, __VA_ARGS__); OutputDebugStringA(debug);}

#define CHECK_READ(status, str) while(0){                                                                               \
                                    if(0 == status){                                                                    \           
                                        DBGPRINT("Message %s\n", str);                  \
                                        return 0;                                                                       \
                                    }                                                                                   \
                                }                                                                                       
int main(){

char* str = "hello world";
status = 0;
CHECK_READ(status, str);

return 0;
}
```

error:

```
Error line  7   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
Error   line 11 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
Error   line 15 error C2017: illegal escape sequence    
Error   line 19 fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

Comment: Don't use macros and raw char* strings in C++ when possible.

Comment: @dark_charlie: in the given case, it would be quite complicated to replace the macro with anything equally compact. But the `char*` strings are evil, of course.

Comment: @Vlad: your macro is a NOOP. It can be replaced with an empty line quite well.

Comment: @Mat: okay, you're right, but consider the customary case of `do { id (cond) return; ... } while (0)`. (And after all, it's not _my_ macro.)

Comment: @yeap: are you sure you posted the whole input file? There is no `{` on input line 1.

Comment: Vlad: the macro you posted is useless as it is, and your code contains syntax errors. Remove it, check that it compiles, and it back piece by piece (making it do something in the process) checking that it compiles step by step.

Comment: @Mat: you couldn't fix the type `id` -> `if` yourself in your mind? :-P and yes, I replaced some code with ellipsis, sapienti sat.

Comment: @Mat: s/type/typo/ in the previous comment :D

Comment: How come the code in your `main` isn't indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's the real answer.

I copy and paste from your code above, and you have trailing whitespace on one of your macro definition lines

```
if(0 == status){               \  WHITESPACE HERE
```

For a blackslash to operate as a line continuation character, it must be the last character on the line, no whitespace afterwards. Now who knows if this is your actual problem, but with the whitespace I got the same errors as you, and without it I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `\` at the end of macro definition. So your `int main(){` line is actually a part of the macro `CHECK_READ` :)

---

EDIT:
The variant without trailing `\` compiles well on ideone: http://ideone.com/pddx0. I declared the `status`, as it's not declared in your code. (I commented out `OutputDebugStringA` and replaced `sprintf_s` with `snprintf`, as they both are Microsoft-specific and wouldn't compile on gcc.)

Comment: didn't help, the same issue :(